# Displaying date time with Php and Oracle. Time fails?

Tags: php, oracle, plsql

I have a small problem. I'm using PHP with Oracle (new to the Oracle by the way).

In my database there's a DATE field called NEXT_START_DATE and it's value is

> 25.12.2013 04:05:01

as you can see below.

[image: Database Record]

The thing is I can get date values just fine in my web page, but couldn't see anything like a time, if you can see below image, it only returns 25/12/2013.

[image]

I know that people suggested to use pl/sql functions like

> to_date()

or

> to_char()

but is this possbile using just php? I really can't interfere the SQL. Any help would be awesome, Thanks in advance.

Comment: please share the query from which you are searching / bringing the records, because it is modifying the result

Comment: in PHP , you fetch it as a date object? `$date->format('d.m.y h:i:s');` wont help ?

Comment: Query is automatically generated by the framework depending on id. In this example the query which is used -> SELECT * FROM FC_VIEW_PACKAGES WHERE ID = %d

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar date comes as string, but as I said, only date is shown, no time

Comment: @FreshPro do you use oci8 ?

Comment: Yes, I got oci functions defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ADOdb`, make sure to set the format before connecting:

```
$db = ADONewConnection("oci8");
// $db->debug = true;

// Date format is set before connecting.
$db->NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
```

**Courtesy:**  http://board.issociate.de/thread/192412/OCI_ignoring_NLS_DATE_FORMAT_parameter.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL functions in your queries as well.

**For example,**

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(next_start_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') FROM mytable
```

and you'll get the date in the format you specified.

As @Maheswaran Ravisankar pointed out, there is NLS_DATE_FORMAT as well, but if you set it, that format is used for all queries (that do not specify to_char). I always use to_char in all my `select`s, because it allows me to specify an individual format for each query.

Comment: The thing I don't understand is, how come I got the correct value in Pl/sql but not in php?

Comment: You get the correct *value* in php as well. You just don't get the correct *format*. The reason for this is that your environment variables (NLS_LANG, NLS_DATE_FORMAT and similar) are probably set differently in your sqlplus environment and your php environment.

Comment: So even if time comes correct, because of my date format is different, it cannot get the time part correctly